# Java | converting 2D int array to 2D char array for println

Tags: java, arrays, char, int, ascii

I am trying to convert a 2D array of ints to 2D array of chars.

I got this far with the code below

```
int[][] boardArray = {
  {0x265C, 0x265E, 0x265D, 0x265B, 0x265A, 0x265D, 0x265E, 0x265C},
  {0x265F, 0x265F, 0x265F, 0x265F, 0x265F, 0x265F, 0x265F, 0x265F},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
  {0x2659, 0x2659, 0x2659, 0x2659, 0x2659, 0x2659, 0x2659, 0x2659},
  {0x2656, 0x2658, 0x2657, 0x2655, 0x2654, 0x2657, 0x2658, 0x2656}};

char[][] arr = new char[boardArray.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < boardArray.length; i++) {
arr[i] = new char[boardArray[i].length];
  for(int j = 0; j < boardArray[i].length; j++){
    arr[i][j] = Integer.toString(boardArray[i][j]).charAt(0);
  }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr)
  .replaceAll("\\[|,", "")
  .replace("] ", ""+System.lineSeparator())
  .replace("]]", ""));
```

**Restrition:**

> I cant change int[][] boardArray to char][] boardArray

---

here is what I am getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHb6L.jpg

here is what I should get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXmWg.jpg

help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `int` to `char` conversion is not correct and should only require a cast. This

```
arr[i][j] = Integer.toString(boardArray[i][j]).charAt(0);
```

should be

```
arr[i][j] = (char) boardArray[i][j];
```

With that one change I get a chessboard like

```
♜ ♞ ♝ ♛ ♚ ♝ ♞ ♜
♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟ ♟
       
       
       
       
♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙ ♙
♖ ♘ ♗ ♕ ♔ ♗ ♘ ♖
```